# React-Redux How to handle slash (/) in production. Redirection from root

Tags: reactjs, build, react-router, production

I have a build package from React, once I deploy it to the server with name **`admin`**, I can not get to that folder with `www.home.com/admin`, so to get to my project I need to append `/` and once I write **`www.home.com/admin/`** my project executes.

I changed in `package.json` `"homepage": "."` to make relative path and I use **HashRouter**

How I can handle this, because every time I need to add `/` to the path in browser

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

import {Route, Switch, HashRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom'
import {store ,persistor} from './components/store/index';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import Display from './components/displayMainScreen/displayMainScreen'
import SignIn from './components/login/indexLogin'
import Logs from './components/logs/logs';


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Provider store={store}>
          <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
            <Router>
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path='/' component = {SignIn} />
                <Route path='/login' component = {SignIn} />
                <Route path='/display' component = {Display} />
                <Route path='/logs' component = {Logs} />
              </Switch>
            </Router>
          </PersistGate>
        </Provider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: i'm not sure if there's enough here to answer the question. this might either be a route-strictness issue in the react app, or it could be a similar route-strictness issue with your web server

Comment: @worc I updated my explanation